# Nginx redirect with rewrite

Tags: nginx

Assuming I want to redirect URIs like

```
http://server1:8081/test/admin/option?options
http://server1:8081/test/admin/option/suboption?options
http://server1:8081/test/admin/option/suboption/subsuboption?options
```

to

```
http://server2:8080/tomcat/admin/option?options
http://server2:8080/tomcat/admin/option/suboption?options
http://server2:8080/tomcat/admin/option/suboption/subsuboption?options
```

what nginx rules I have to use? I've tried the following but it doesn't work

```
location =/test/admin {
  proxy_pass http://server2:8080/tomcat/admin;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines ..

```
location /test/admin {
    rewrite ^/test/admin(.*)$ /tomcat/admin$1;
}

location /tomcat/admin {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://server2:8080;
    […]
}
```

That is, rewrite the requests to "tomcat/admin" which you can optionally make open to [internal requests](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) only.

In that location block, you can then `proxy pass`the request.

Comment: Thank you very much! One notice is I want to use more general rewrite rule, like `"rewrite ^/test/admin(.*)$ /tomcat/admin$1 last;"`. Hopefully, that works too

Comment: That should work. More efficient since you just need one rule as well. You wouldnt neccesarily need the "last" flag for a single rule.